# Python debug logger doesn't appear in console

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is driving me insane, I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import logging


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print(logger.getEffectiveLevel())
print(logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG))
logger.debug("test") #???
```

which, when run, outputs the following:

```
10
True
```

why doesn't my `logger.debug` statement do anything???

Comment: _why doesn't my `logger.debug` statement do anything???_ What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @scharette I mean it didn't output anything, which is what I expected it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't configure any handler.  Without a handler configured, the log event goes nowhere.  When there are no handlers configured, the root logger gets a handler automatically added if an event at WARNING or above is seen, but your event was just at DEBUG.

Try this instead:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()  # this is the root logger
>>> logger.handlers
[]
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.handlers
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
>>> logger.debug('test')
DEBUG:root:test
```

Basic config will add a `StreamHandler` writing to `sys.stderr` if you don't specify otherwise.

At this point, I invite you to consider [a 3rd-party logging framework](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with more sensible defaults than the stdlib logging.

```
>>> import structlog
>>> logger = structlog.get_logger()
>>> logger.debug("test message", key1='val1', key2='val2')
2018-07-23 13:13.28 test message                   key1=val1 key2=val2
```

Comment: Thanks. The docs were pretty unclear about that. I was under the impression that calling the `getLogger` function _would_ get the root logger, so then I could set the root logger's level myself with `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`. To be clear, that's not the case, and what I got wasn't the root logger? Also, I'd appreciate it if your answer contained a totally complete solution, i.e. with import and setup for the objects used.

Comment: okay, well in that case I'm still prepared to accept your answer if you add `import logging` and `logger = logging.getLogger()`, but it'd be really nice if you could also figure out why what I did _didn't_ work.

Comment: I'm tired of figuring out why stdlib logging doesn't work half the time. Just use 3rd party if you can, there are lots of good choices (structlog, logbook, shoehorn...)